# Запись файлов, производительность

Tags: java, многопоточность, производительность

При параллельной многопоточности, с точки зрения производительности,
важен ли порядок следования записей в выходных файлах?

Comment: Какой порядок? Каких файлах?

Comment: _порядок следования записей в выходных файлах_ - Вы хотите, чтобы несколько потоков записывали данные в один и тот же файл?

Comment: именно так, вопрос в том повлияет ли на производительность последовательность записи

Comment: Для SSD, я думаю, пофиг. А для HDD крайне желателен последовательный доступ к секторам диска. Если головка будет метаться туда-сюда - время будет тратиться впустую.

Comment: В этом есть логика, спасибо.

Comment: Если два потока имеют доступ к одной переменной, это уже создает трудности, а Вы хотите записывать в файл из n потоков! Мне кажется, это ужасная идея. Непонятно, что и как будет записываться. А если один поток закроет OutputStream, в то время как другой будет в него писать?